# what is the most common way (or ways) to insert roles in database during database creation

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security

I am using spring security + hibernate and command

```
?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

to instantiate database on app start. I want to fill one of tables with base roles for spring security if new database is created. What is the most common way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring Boot, you can place an import.sql file under the resources folder.  Hibernate should be set to create or create/drop

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create/drop
```

The import.sql file will be executed on application startup if the database tables were created.

```
#import.sql

INSERT INTO role (id, name) VALUES (1, 'ROLE_USER');
INSERT INTO role (id, name) VALUES (2, 'ROLE_ADMIN');
```

---

Spring Boot documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate